# Why is Ethereum Uncle rate so low?

Tags: ether, gas, uncle-blocks

In Ethereum 1.0, the block creation time is only about 12-15 seconds. So, we may expect that there will be many uncles. But, practically, the uncle rate is very small.
Why is the uncle rate is low?